# Loading XMLDocument child nodes to textboxes?

Tags: c#, xml, xpath

I want to load some XML child nodes into specific text boxes, but can only find examples of how to do it by creating an XMLNodeList of the XmlDocument child nodes, and iterating through them as a list and calling them by index. Is there a way to get specific child nodes in my XMLDocument by tag names?

```
//my xml file
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Textboxes>
    <FirstName>John</FirstName>
    <LastName>Smith</LastName>
</Textboxes>

    //c# method to load textboxes by child node names
    private void LoadTextboxes()
    {
        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        doc.Load(Application.StartupPath + "\\Saved.xml");

        txtFirstName.Text = doc.??? // get <FirstName>
        txtLastName.Text = doc.??? // get <LastName>   
    }
```

Comment: XPath filtering? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256086(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the sample you provided, something like this should work:

```
private static void LoadTextboxes()
{
    XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
    doc.Load(Application.StartupPath + @"\Saved.xml");
    txtFirstName.Text = doc.LastChild.SelectSingleNode("FirstName").LastChild.Value; // get <FirstName>
    txtLastName.Text = doc.LastChild.SelectSingleNode("LastName").LastChild.Value; // get <LastName>   
}
```